# How Can I Setup a FTP-Client Connection on embedded device?

Tags: c++, c, ftp, stm32, mbed

I work on a FTP script for a mbed project. I work with the B-L475E-IOT01A development board and try to send a file to a FTP-Server. Therefore I cant establish a connection with the server with this libary https://os.mbed.com/users/dkato/code/ftp-client/#e069c405c934.
Unfortunaly the client doesnt work like it should work.
I try to establish connection like this:

```
bool FTPClient::open(const char* ip_addr, int port, const char* user, const char* pass)
{
    SocketAddress ftpAddress(ip_addr, port);

    //Connect to SocketAddress while using FTP Clients Network interface
    FTPClientControlSock.open(p_network);
    if (FTPClientControlSock.connect(ftpAddress) < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return false;
    }

    //recieve ftp server message
    if (FTPClientControlSock.recv(p_ftp_buf, FTP_BUF_SIZE) <= 0) {
        printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return false;
    }

    //prove ftp server message equals ftp server information messages (starting with not logged in code 220)
    if (strncmp(p_ftp_buf, "220", 3) != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return false;
    }

    //store user info in ftp communication and send it
    sprintf(p_ftp_buf, "USER %s\r\n", user);
    printf("%s", p_ftp_buf);
    FTPClientControlSock.send(p_ftp_buf, strlen(p_ftp_buf));

    //recieve ftp server info and print it
    if (FTPClientControlSock.recv(p_ftp_buf, FTP_BUF_SIZE) <= 0) {
        printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return false;
    }
    printf("%s", p_ftp_buf);

    //prove ftp server message equals ftp server information messages (begin with code 331)
    if (strncmp(p_ftp_buf, "331", 3) != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return false;
    }

    //store password in string and send it to server
    sprintf(p_ftp_buf, "PASS %s\r\n", pass);
    printf("%s", p_ftp_buf);
    FTPClientControlSock.send(p_ftp_buf, strlen(p_ftp_buf));

    //recieve ftp server info and print it
    if (FTPClientControlSock.recv(p_ftp_buf, FTP_BUF_SIZE) <= 0) {
        printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return false;
    }

    //check login was successful
    if (strncmp(p_ftp_buf, "230", 3) != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return false;
    }

    printf("%s", p_ftp_buf);
    return true;
}
```

On the Terminal after this i get an output like this in the console:

```
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 4 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 02:42. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
USER user
PASS pass
331 User user OK. Password required
is now 02:42. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
ERROR: ./ftp-client/FTPClient.cpp(96) //this is the line where the code 230 gets checked
```

I dont know really where my mistake is. I expected a successful login and a clear communication to the ftp server. Can you help me pls?

Comment: Your output seems odd, specifically the line that starts with "is now" that has no status code (I'd also expect your "PASS" print to be after the "331"). You might want to add a prefix and suffix to your prints to see the boundaries. Assuming your last `recv` got all that, it looks like either the server or your socket library had some sort of hiccup and repeated previous data.

Comment: @Hasturkun, he also can send both USER XXX and PASS yyy in sequence and receive the two messages after that.... this is not a problem of comunication between server and client, it is how you interpret the logged output from the client.... you can send multiple commands in batch because each has a response in FTP protocol.

Comment: @LuisColorado: That's true, but his code handles these one by one (and prints them in the same order), which is why I thought the output was odd (The reversal of "PASS" and the "331" for one). I will say that the code is rather optimistic about `recv` returning everything at once, and prints assume strings are NUL terminated (which they probably are not, likely the reason for the output repeating).

Comment: @Hasturkun, the strings will be `\0` terminated, or they will not be strings.  not in C.  The normal is that you use `getchar()` and parse correctly the input, and you'll get normally well formed strings delimited by a three digit code, followed with - or space, then a message string, ended in CRLF sequence.  If you read with `read(2)` then you have an array of chars, not ended in `\0`, but if you read with `getchar()` then you need to add the `\0` yourself to treat the thing as a string. Also you are required to parse TELNET escape sequences.

Comment: @LuisColorado: Thanks, I'm aware of how C strings work. The point is that `recv()` will not NUL terminate the read content for you.

Comment: @Hasturkun, `recv(2)` will not, but `getchar(3)` will give you a buffered input, char by char.  I have never spoke about `recv(2)` or `read(2)` because they are non-buffered system calls that lead to very inefficient code.  IMHO the best is to build the string yourself with a finite state automaton, that allows you to precisely detect server return code, continuation line, proper line ending and extracting the TELNET control sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julien, all the responses from the server follow a pattern..  you need to wait for a `\r\n` sequence from the server.  You need to filter TELNET protocol escape sequences (that start with the byte 0xff or 0xfe, I don't remember from my head) and the codes must be always at the beginning of a line.  Also the numbers with a `-` instead of a space indicate that the message is larger and you should expect another line (the last line of each message has a numeric code followed by a space)

This is essential to maintain yourself synchronized with the server.... or you'll start receiving responses to different commands than the one you think.

From the output it is not clear what you try to do, as the only thing you show is the login part to the server.

Your command lines also have (this is mandatory by the protocol) to end in a sequence `\r\n` (in that order) you cannot do else, or you can reach a server that doesn't understand you.

Check [RFC-959 - File Transfer Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) for details on how the ftp protocol works.  The transfers are normally handled in a new, different TCP connection, so you normally have to manage the control connection plus a series of data transfers that run in parallel with it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Unfortunally I am new to embedded programming. 
You are right: It is not clear so far, what I am trying to do. I want to put files I create with this board to the FTP server. But I didnt get any further than trying to connect so far, so I dont know if there is a problem with the put function. How can I wait for the \r\n end sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally got the connection established. It was correct to synchronize the server and the client. Furthermore I needed to free up the buffer from time to time and the output is less confusing now. Here is my code:

```
bool FTPClient::open(const char *ip_addr, int port, const char *user,
                 const char *pass) {


// Convert into SocketAddress
  SocketAddress ftpAddress(ip_addr, port);

  // Close FTP connection if open
  if (_ctr_open) {
    FTPClientControlSock.close();
  }

  // Connect to SocketAddress while using FTP Clients Network interface
  FTPClientControlSock.open(p_network);
  if (FTPClientControlSock.connect(ftpAddress) < 0) {
    printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return false;
  }

  // set connection to true
  _ctr_open = true;

  // recieve ftp server messages and print if correct
  if (FTPClientControlSock.recv(p_ftp_buf, FTP_BUF_SIZE) <= 0) {
    printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return false;
  }
  if (strncmp(p_ftp_buf, "220", 3) != 0) {
    printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return false;
  } else {
    printf("%s", p_ftp_buf);
    _login = false;
  }
  wait_us(2000000);
  memset(p_ftp_buf, 0, strlen(p_ftp_buf));

  if (FTPClientControlSock.recv(p_ftp_buf, FTP_BUF_SIZE) <= 0) {
    printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return false;
  }
  if (strncmp(p_ftp_buf, "220", 3) != 0) {
    printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return false;
  } else {
    printf("%s", p_ftp_buf);
    _login = false;
  }
  wait_us(2000000);
  memset(p_ftp_buf, 0, strlen(p_ftp_buf));

  // store user info in ftp communication print and send it
  sprintf(p_ftp_buf, "USER %s\r\n", user);
  FTPClientControlSock.send(p_ftp_buf, strlen(p_ftp_buf));

  // recieve ftp server message and print if correct
  if (FTPClientControlSock.recv(p_ftp_buf, FTP_BUF_SIZE) <= 0) {
    printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return false;
  }
  if (strncmp(p_ftp_buf, "331", 3) != 0) {
    printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return false;
  } else {
    printf("%s", p_ftp_buf);
    _login = false;
  }
  wait_us(2000000);
  memset(p_ftp_buf, 0, strlen(p_ftp_buf));

  // store password in string and send it to server
  sprintf(p_ftp_buf, "PASS %s\r\n", pass);
  FTPClientControlSock.send(p_ftp_buf, strlen(p_ftp_buf));
  wait_us(2000000);

  // recieve ftp server info and print it
  if (FTPClientControlSock.recv(p_ftp_buf, FTP_BUF_SIZE) <= 0) {
    printf("LINE: %d\r\n", __LINE__);
    printf("%s", p_ftp_buf);
    printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return false;
  } else {
    wait_us(3000000);
    printf("%s", p_ftp_buf);
  }
  if (FTPClientControlSock.recv(p_ftp_buf, FTP_BUF_SIZE) <= 0) {
    printf("LINE: %d\r\n", __LINE__);
    printf("%s", p_ftp_buf);
    printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return false;
  } else {
    wait_us(3000000);
    printf("%s", p_ftp_buf);
  }

  // check login was successful
  if (strncmp(p_ftp_buf, "230", 3) != 0) {
    printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return false;
  }

  memset(p_ftp_buf, 0, strlen(p_ftp_buf));
  _login = true;
  return true;
}
```

I get the output:

```
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 4 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 03:25. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
331 User user OK. Password required
230-Your bandwidth usage is restricted
230-OK. Current restricted directory is /
230 1941 Kbytes used (0%) - authorized: 2048000 Kb
FTP Connection successful
```

Thank you for helping me.